# Обработчик события CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Имеется сторонний контрол, который биндится к коллекции, имплементирующей [CollectionChagned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Проблема в том что коллекция обновляется слишком часто, из-за чего при отрисовке подвисает UI.

Какими путями можно добиться "прореживания" обработки события [CollectionChagned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

P.S. коллекция тоже от стороннего контрола, я не могу самостоятельно вызывать `OnCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Хм, ну пропустим мы часть событий, но тогда GUI и не все изменения ведь отобразит... У вас в коллекции много элементов?

Comment: я не уверен что при отрисовке учитываются только новые элементы. Коллекция сама не большая, можно в принципе сделать замену всей коллекции..

Comment: Можно попробовать написать декоратор, проглатывающий часть событий. Но если коллекция небольшая, можно периодически делать что-то вроде `List2 = List1.ToList()`, где `List1` - ваша быстроизменяющаяся коллекция, а `List2` - новая коллекция, которую привязываем в GUI

Comment: У меня была та же проблема, я использовал Reactive Extensions - [Throttle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Попробуйте для начала такой декоратор: https://pastebin.com/1RGx4fiZ

Comment: @tym32167, но ведь все равно придется писать какую-то оболочку для коллекции, реализующую INCC...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я попробовал декоратор, похоже не происходит подписывание на CollectionChanged вовсе

Comment: @АндрейNOP может и придется, зато своего кода не надо будет писать для троттлинга событий. Хотя я сам не фанат RX, но в моем случае оно хорошо зашло

Comment: @Gardes, надеюсь, не первую версию, которую я без реализации `IEnumerable` сделал, использовали (вроде я ее быстро потер)? Покажите что написали

Comment: @АндрейNOP, https://pastebin.com/vminsKdj, вторую версию

Comment: @Gardes, у меня нормально подхватывается, но те события, которые были пропущены в GUI не отображаются, как я и предполагал, значит способ с декоратором не прокатит. Остается только периодически делать штампы коллекции и выводить их в GUI

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну или качать весь исходник и править) в любом случае спасибо за помощь

Comment: @АндрейNOP хотя бы ответом код кинули, так же и делают, если предлагают код как ответ (просто у меня пастебины/гисты заблочены)

Comment: @tym32167, лениво + надо домой собираться с работы + код с пастебина не нужен, т.к. это решение не работает как нужно. Может вечером, а может завтра опубликую. А может кто-то хорошее решение опубликует раньше меня, я бы тоже с удовольствием посмотрел

Comment: Ну Rx как бы канонический метод бороться с backpressure.

Answer (score 1):

Если коллекция небольшая, то можно периодически делать ее дамп и выводить в GUI именно его вместо исходной коллекции.

Я набросал такой пример: исходная коллекция заполняется по таймеру каждые 20 мс, дамп создается каждые 100 мс:

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    public ICommand StartUpdatingCommand { get; }
    public ICommand StopUpdatingCommand { get; }
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public ObservableCollection<int> Collection { get; }

    IEnumerable<int> collectionDump;
    public IEnumerable<int> CollectionDump
    {
        get => collectionDump;
        set => Set(ref collectionDump, value, nameof(CollectionDump));
    }

    public MainVm()
    {
        StartUpdatingCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => StartUpdating());
        StopUpdatingCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => StopUpdating());

        Collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        CollectionDump = Collection.ToArray();

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20) };
        timer.Tick += delegate { Collection.Add(10); Collection.Add(20); if (Collection.Count > 100) Collection.Clear(); };
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async void StartUpdating()
    {
        if (cancellationTokenSource != null) return;
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                CollectionDump = Collection.ToArray();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        finally
        {
            cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }
    }

    private void StopUpdating()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Разметка содержимого окна:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionDump}"/>

    <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" Rows="1">
        <UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5"/>
            </Style>
        </UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Button Content="Start updating" Command="{Binding StartUpdatingCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Stop updating" Command="{Binding StopUpdatingCommand}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Обратите внимание, привязка именно к `CollectionDump`